# How to extract results from multiple query results tabs into one excel in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to save results of multiple queries into a single excel sheet. Is there any way to do this in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: spool the output of all queries from the same SQL worksheet. into a  csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Query results exports for XLSX go to a single file.

So you could copy and paste the results over, which is admittedly, not ideal. And you could try what others have suggested, spooling the data as CSV to a file, and let Excel figure it out later.

Here's one way to do it, but will require CREATE VIEW privs for your Oracle user:

Create the queries as VIEWs, and then export the views to a single Excel file. Each view will go to a separate workbook.

I talk about that [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/01/exporting-multiple-tables-to-a-single-excel-file-using-sql-developers-cart/).

Open your cart, drag in the views, set your options, and export to single excel file.

[image]

[image]

If it were me, I'd create an Oracle Application Express app, and keep the data out of Excel, period.

Comment: Hi Jeff, hope you dont mind If  I have a related question:)  I read one of your articles describing how to export the tables with `BLOB` columns from a table and we are exporting them as `sqlldr` files from SQL dev. That seems to be the only viable option for us(in one particular module) now which is conveniently portable for continuous deployments. Are there any other options in SQL dev which is convenient to export `BLOB` ?. If the answer is detailed, I will ask it as a separate question. Appreciate your time!

Comment: that's the best way to get BLOBs out...unless you want to talk about Data Pump